# what's the difference in angular between bootstrap method and run method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently using `bootstrap` angular to run my application in this way:

```
ng.bootstrap(document, ['main']);
```

Angular docs states that

```
Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. 
A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application.
```

So what's the difference between them?

Comment: any special reason for doing so? bootstrapping is implict by adding ng-app = "appName" in your index.html

Comment: I'm loading a bunch of files using requirejs, when all dependencies  are resolved only then I can start the application

Comment: I am guessing you are not allowed to define constants or values in the bootstrap function. also you can enable or disabling debugging in bootstrap, I believe.

Comment: @z.a., bootstrap method doesn't accept any function/handler

Comment: nothing happens without the bootstrap, `run` is not required

Comment: it does accept a config object...

Comment: z.a. yeah, but how would you define constants and values in this config?

Comment: @charlietfl, ok, but what's the difference in their purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` method just adds functions that need to be called once injector is created and modules being initialized. These functions usually contain methods to intitialize module. Whereas, `bootstrap` method tells `angular` to create injector and start executing functions added with `config` and `run` methods. So the order of execution is roughly like that:

```
1. Create injector
2. Execute functions added with config() method for each module
3. Execute functions added with run() method for each module
4. Start compilation phase
5. Start linking phase
```